# No OnActivate method found to be overriden

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

Trying to add a file picker using `FileOpenPicker` and since I'm targeting Win 8.1 the async method to pick the file is not implemented, so I just have to use the `picksinglefileandcontinue` and based on "what I read over the stackoverflow (don't know to what extent these people are right or wrong)" there must be an `OnActivated` method to be triggered upon re-activating the app once the file has been picked but Visual Studio claims that such method does not exits at all.

Assuming that:

```
public partial class Test: Page {}
```

the base class does not have the `OnActivate` method to be overridden.

Since there is no property to return the file path what is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OnActivated` event can be overridden in *App.xaml.cs* file, not directly in Page (View):

```
 protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
 {
       base.OnActivated(args);

       //Handle continuation here
 }
```

[HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn631755.aspx) is the sample how to handle it.